# React > Conditionally Check either one prop is available

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working with following code,

```
MessageDialog.propTypes = {
    message: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    processedMessage: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
}
```

I want to know is there any way to set either message or processedMessage 
"isRequired" where it will only searching for either one of the above two to be true at any time.

Answer (score 0):

You might need the custom checker like the following:

```
function messageOrProcessedIsRequired(props, propName, componentName) {
  return  (!props.hasOwnProperty('message') && 
             !props.hasOwnProperty('processedMessage')) 
            && new Error(`Either "message" or "processedMessage" is required in component ${componentName}.`);
}

MessageDialog.propTypes = {
    message: messageOrProcessedIsRequired,
    processedMessage: messageOrProcessedIsRequired
}
```

Comment: Solved the issue. Thank you very much!

Comment: Your are Welcome 